# Can not load webpage in Rest webservice using apache wink

Tags: html, rest, tomcat, ant, apache-wink

I have successfully implemented rest webservice using apache wink. I am using ant to build war and to deploy it to tomcat server. Now I want include html or jsp file in the project to display some results. But I dont know how to include it via ant build file. I tried copy and pasting the html file in the root folder as well as web-inf folder in tomcat's webapp folder and than restarted it. But so far I am not able to access it. Whenever I try to access html page it gives me error

org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor - The following error occurred during the invocation of the handlers chain: WebApplicationException (404 - Not Found) with message 'null' while processing GET request sent to http://localhost:8080/outliers/index.html

Please help me how can I include html file in my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you should just put the html file in the war's root directory. \

Don't put it in WEB-INF, it's is not accessible from the web!

If the html file in root directory, and you still cannot access it, check that tomcat started without errors. Sometimes errors are not displayed in console, so check the logs.